# Problem with opening and closing links, tabs, and windows in ubuntu

Tags: 20.04

Having a problem that is particularly frustrating. Often when I open a link in either firefox or chrome, it open a new tab. When I click on a tab it sometimes will close it. When I click to close a tab it sometimes does nothing. This problem doesn't seem limited to the browser because when I click on an application icon on the left side icon bar to reopen it, it will sometimes open a new iteration of it. Also, if I have text copied and I click on a search bar to type something it will automatically paste it. Help is appreciated.

*Note- I use the word "sometimes" for all of these problems but really I mean to say, more and more often

Comment: A bad mouse maybe?

Comment: I use a keypad... but not I don't think its that